# How can I make my own timer without standard library?

Tags: c++, loops, timer

Is there some specific number of iterations, that I could make using a `for loop`, so that it exactly takes 1 second for the loop to be executed completely? For example the following code took 0.125s on my machine to execute:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace  std;

int main(){
    long long a=0;

    for (a=0;a<=pow(10,4);a++);
}
```

Though, a <= 8*pow(10,4) took 0.206 s. Compiler is GCC 4.9.2. IDE is codeblocks.

My PC's Specs: OS: Windows 8.1
[image]

Comment: Probably not, because the compiler may optimize different code differently.

Comment: Sure. A busy-loop calling `clock()` over and over. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: The time that an iteration will take is *unpredictable*, this can not work with just a for loop. Not only does this depend on the CPU used, but you need to take into account power management, the scheduler, etc.

Comment: You'd have to use a real time OS to accomplish that. There's too much jitter in non realtime OSs. Windows could decide to schedule other processes for a while, or use the CPU for e.g. kernel networking, disk I/O etc. that preempts your timing.

Comment: I don't see reasons to downvote.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar just for fun, sometimes, I like experimenting!

Comment: You can't "make your own timer" in a hosted environment just in standard C++. A timer is essentially a mechanism to communicate with the OS scheduler, and you need platform-specific OS services for that.

Comment: Building on @πάνταῥεῖ's comment: as it is, your loop will be removed through dead code elimination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting  this answer to your question, as per the comments received.

It is not possible to make a timer because:

- The time that an iteration will take is unpredictable, this depends not only on the CPU used, but you need to take into account power management, the scheduler. (By tux3)
- one would have to use a real time OS to accomplish that. There's too much jitter in non realtime OSs. Windows could decide to schedule other processes for a while, or use the CPU for e.g. kernel networking, disk I/O etc. that preempts the timing. (By nos)
- One can't "make own timer" in a hosted environment just in standard C++. A timer is essentially a mechanism to communicate with the OS scheduler, and one needs platform-specific OS services for that. (By Kerrek SB)
- The compiler would optimize such a loop and will remove it through dead-code elimination (By  πάντα ῥεῖ and Jongware).