# Text based game with a separate timer loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have started a Java coding short course at a university about 5 months ago. I have learnt quite the amount of things with regards to Java coding, but am still lacking in other things such as threads, handling exceptions, or even making `JFrame` games. I decided to embark on a text based game to just learn and figure out how a game loop should work (kind of), and how the logic should work (still, very "kind of"). The game I wrote runs with `if-else` commands, thus you get displayed a screen, type in the command of the option you want to pick, and it bumps you to the next menu, very standard of course. I run these `if-else` statements within nested `for` loops.

My nested `for` loops looks like the following:

```
    // This is just an example, they're actually a lot more cluttered
    // in my actual source code.

    mainMenu.writeOutput();

    reply = keyboardInput.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i--)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; i <= 10; i--)
        {
             if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("/help")
             {
                 System.out.println("Here I have a separate call to a class
                     file (excuse me, forgot the exact wording), thus it
                     call something like help.writeOutput(); to display
                     the help menu");

                 reply = keyboardInput.nextLine();

                 if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("/makegameeasy")
                 {
                     // Just an example.
                     gamedifficultyEasy.writeOutput();

                     reply = keyboardInput.nextLine();

                     if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("/back")
                     {
                         mainMenu.writeOutput();

                         reply = keyboardInput.nextLine();

                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 else if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("/makegamedifficult")
                 {
                     // Another example.
                     gamedifficultHard.writeOutput();

                     reply = keyboardInput.nextLine();

                     if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("/back")
                     {
                         mainMenu.writeOutput();

                         reply = keyboardInput.nextLine();

                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 else if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("/back")
                 {
                     mainMenu.writeOutput();

                     reply = keyboardInput.nextLine();

                     break;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Here I print out an error for incorrect
                     input received, standard fare.");

                 mainMenu.writeOutput();

                 reply = keyboard.nextLine();

                 break;
             }
         }
     }
```

As mentioned, the above is just an example, it's not very elegant, and I can probably use Exceptions for any incorrect info submitted by the user, however I do not know too much of Exceptions to comfortably add them, so I'll do that at a later time, however my main issue at the moment is a part of my game where "resource mining" has to be done on regular intervals. I have been all over Google, but still can't quite catch how to set a `Thread` or `Timer` up for my game so it does the mining automatically, and the player can go on with their game.

The game is essentially one of those games where you build up a base, upgrade your mining tools, and generate more "stuff". I have pasted a few blocks of code from my "mining" class file below that will basically run how much of one thing should be mined. In the game you will be able to buy upgrades of course, so it will get factored into your mining speed.

```
    // I initiate my variables a lot earlier, but just for some
    // clarity, I have initiated the variables in the below methods,
    // they will not work correctly anyway, I am aware of that, however
    // I didn't want to add the other "get, set and initiate"
    // variables and methods everywhere, as to not spam this block of code.

    // upgradeOS, upgradeHF, and upgradeLM all have their own respective
    // set and get methods. They are also all int variables.

    public void handleOS()
    {
        // OS = short for Oxygen Silo

        int mineOS = os.getStoredO2() + (1 * upgradeOS);

        os.setStoredO2(mineOS);
    }

    public void handleHF()
    {
        // HF = short for Hydrogen Fuel

        int mineHF = hf.getStoredO2() + (1 * upgradeHF);

        hf.setStoredO2(mineHF);
    }

    public void handleLM()
    {
        // LM = short for Liquid Minerals

        int mineLM = lm.getStoredMinerals() + (1 * upgradeLM);

        lm.setStoredMinerals(mineLM);
    }

    // This is what's going to run the whole time on the set intervals.
    public void mine()
    {
        mineOS = os.getStoredO2() + (1 * upgradeOS);
        mineHF = hf.getStoredO2() + (1 * upgradeHF);
        mineLM = lm.getStoredMinerals() + (1 * upgradeLM);

        os.setStoredO2(mineOS);
        hf.setStoredO2(mineHF);
        lm.setStoredMinerals(mineLM);
    }

    // Using 10 seconds here to have it update as quickly as possible so I can
    // see any changes. This is just here to write an output.
    public void getUpgradeInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Oxygen: " + (1 * upgradeOS) + " / per 10 seconds.");
        System.out.println("Hydrogen: " + (1 * upgradeHF) + " / per 10 seconds.");
        System.out.println("Liquid Mineral: " + (1 * upgradeLM) + " / per 10 seconds.");
    }
```

I'm not the best naming schemes for my materials...

TL;DR: I can't figure out how to implement a `thread` or `timer` just for the above mentioned `mine()` method since I do not have the appropriate amount of knowledge. My `if-else` rules aren't too elegant, but I'll work on those of course. Basically the `if-else` rules should run separately from the `mine()` method, and you can do some AFKing without the game updating the `System.out` output, thus you can be floating in, for example, the Oxygen Silo upgrade menu, and you won't be bounced back to a different menu due to a thread "waking up", such as being bounced to the main menu, but the `mine()` method will still generate resources in the background as it should.

Any help on this, or just even a nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828774/how-can-i-make-my-own-timer-without-standard-library)

Comment: @anshabhi Hmm, I am not hell bent on exact timing, basically just a Thread to be implemented that will sleep for a few seconds, and then wake up to do another cycle of "mining" without disturbing the actual person playing by automatically refreshing the game. Also, I am looking at `thread` or `timer`, not specifically limiting the speed on how a `for` loop takes place, even if it were possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question you asked, you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    mine();
  }
}

Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000);
```

Alternatively, you can use an `ActionListener` and the [swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) in a similar way. This has the advantage of being Thread-safe in case you build a swing gui on top

Lastly, you should check out the usage of `synchronized` and `volatile` to make sure that the variable(s) that are updated in `mine()` are done so in a thread-safe way

Comment: You sir, deserve a cookie. It all works as it should with a bit of "changing", posted my own code below as reference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ControlAltDel, definite shove in the right direction. I have taken a bit of code and set it up like this:

```
import java.util.*;

// extends TimerTask needed
public class TimerTestOne extends TimerTask
{
    // Needed
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        TimerTestTwo ttt = new TimerTestTwo();

        mine();
    }

    // Needed, method doesn't need the same name though.
    private void completeTask()
    {
        try
        {
            //assuming it takes 10 secs to complete the task
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // You will need to define the following line of code:
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTestOne();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String reply;

        // Following 2 lines of code, yup, need them.
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 10*1000);

        previousMenu();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii <= 10000; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Go to another menu?");

                reply = keyboard.nextLine();

                if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("/yes"))
                {
                    yes();

                    reply = keyboard.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // I added the following methods, just so I didn't have to work
    // off 2 class files.
    public void mine()
    {
        System.out.println("Mined");
    }

    public static void yes()
    {
        System.out.println("Next menu");
    }

    public static void previousMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("Previous menu");
    }
}
```

So there, if anyone ever needs to have a look at setting a timer up that won't break your text based game.

Comment: Glad you've got it to work! I have also updated my answer to include some information on making your code thread safe